# Scalar action using the Hodge Laplacian

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Just like a gravitational action may be written as an integration over forms, namely $$S = \int_{\mathcal{M}} \star F_{ab}\wedge e^a \wedge e^b$$
(here $\star$ is not the hodge action but $\star F_{ab} = \epsilon_{abcd}F^{cd}$). I wonder if I can similarly write the curved space scalar action as an integration over a form. One immediate idea is $$S_1 = \int_{\mathcal{M}}\phi~ d^{\dagger}d~\phi$$ where $d^{\dagger}d$ is the Hodge Laplacian which just a fancy way to write the usual Laplacian in terms of exterior derivative operators. However, the above is not entirely correct as it doesn't give the correct $\sqrt{g}$ volume factor, hence, we are compelled propose the following
$$S_2 = \int_{\mathcal{M}}*(\phi~ d^{\dagger}d~\phi)$$

However, mathematically both are valid as $S_1$ is an integration over a zero-form form while $S_2$ is an integration over a hodge-dual of a zero form. Both will give the same equation of motion. But physics-wise which is the correct curved-space action for the scalar field?

Comment: How do you integrate a 0-form over anything other than a 0-dimensional manifold?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Oh you can't ? I am sorry I wasn't aware of this. Can you explain why can we only integrate over an $m$-form in $m$-dimensions?

Comment: @user44690 this is definitional for forms. But even dimensionally, an $m$-form is like a product of $m$ differentials and hence would have "units" like an $m$-dimensional volume.

Comment: @user44690 there's an actual reason for integrating top forms which is the Jacobian determinant in the formula for changes of variables in an integral (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChangeofVariablesTheorem.html). Briefly: top forms are, in particular, tensors, and the change of variables formula for top forms produces a determinant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can only integrate an *n*-form over an *n*-dimensional manifold in a coordinate-independent way.  Since the Hodge dual of a 0-form is an *n*-form, $S_2$ is a well-defined quantity (independent of coordinates), but $S_1$ is not.

As to why *n*-forms are the "natural" objects to integrate on *n*-dimensional manifold, I'm not an expert;  hopefully someone will give a more thorough answer here.  In addition, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1252730/a-question-on-integration-of-differential-forms-on-a-manifold) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829285/the-integral-of-a-function-on-manifold-and-differential-form/1829292) over on Math.SE might help elucidate things.

Answer (score 4):

You want
$$
\int d\phi\wedge \star d\phi\,.
$$

This appears in e.g. (2.2) of https://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.4032.pdf

Comment: I believe that this is equivalent to the OP's version of the Lagrangian up to a boundary term.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: as you pointed out, OP's S_1 is wrong. You are correct that S_2 is equivalent to what I wrote up to sign factors and boundary terms, but boundary terms matter. The form I wrote is also the one most commonly found in the literature and it manifestly reduces to the usual Klein Gordon action on flat spacetime.

Comment: @alexarvanitakis Can you please provide a reference to the literature where you found the scalar action written this way?

Comment: @user44690 done